# Python 2.7 ImportError: No module named repository

Tags: 14.04, python, gtk

I'm completely clueless. I uninstalled, and re installed gi and python2.7. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
~ > /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> import gi.repository
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named repository
```

Thank you!

Comment: does this help http://askubuntu.com/questions/80448/what-would-cause-the-gi-module-to-be-missing-from-python

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment! Checked that post. Reconfigured python2.7. Reinstalled python-gobject and python-gobject-2. /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is in path. gi exists. For some reason gi.repository doesn't. Not sure what that is. @mchid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your responses.

I had another version of python installed in my /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I would highly recommend the use of virtual environments. This solves any conflicting dependency problems. They are very easy to install, and it basically creates a standalone python environment for each virtualenv. That way, you can use version 1 of package X in Project Y, but use version 2 of package X in Project Z, without running into dependency he'll.

Comment: I mainly use Python through the anaconda distribution to avoid Matlab. I started  dappling with gui interfaces through  GTK when I some how broke everything . Would a virtual environment work for that to avoid messing with my system's install of python? i.e. be able to access ubuntu's notifications, and panel?

Comment: Most definitely.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the following package instead:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi
```

> This package contains the Python 2.x binding generator for libraries
>   that support gobject-introspection, i. e. which ship a
>   gir1.2-- package. With these packages, the libraries
>   can be used from Python.

Comment: I already removed and re installed python-gi

Comment: That's weird, did you start your interpreter inside a venv? If yes try with `mkvirtualenv environment  --system-site-packages` instead

Comment: Hey @Sylvain Pineau thanks for help! I don't believe so. I just found that gobject-introspection was missing though! Sadly, I can still not import gi.repository or run software-center.

Answer (score 2):

Type the command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Ubuntu 16.04. My issue was an update of the python package using `pip`.

My solution was to remove the package with pip and reinstall it with apt-get:

```
sudo -H pip uninstall gi

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi
```

I agree with Sylvain Pineau, but just reinstalling `python-gi` with `apt-get` was not enough for me.